# Set image src from ajax post to rest api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Is this possible?  My ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: "/reporter/api/image/getimage/",
    data: { "": httpNonAccessibleFilePath },
    success: function ( imageData ) {
        $( "#imagecontent" ).append( '<img src="' + imageData + '" />' );
    }
} );
```

And on my Web.API side:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage([FromBody]string serverPath)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    if (serverPath != null)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(serverPath);
        if (fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            response.Content = new StreamContent( fileInfo.OpenRead() );
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue( "image/png" );
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

All the bits are wired up okay, i.e. I can hit the service and it returns data... but I don't see any images.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure  $( "#imagecontent" ) is already in DOM?

Comment: Forget about this. I forgot to look at the second piece of code. Another question is, what does your API return? A URI or the actual image contents?

Comment: @roasted Yep.  I see the broken image icons loaded up into that image area.  And if I return just a string with a url to some random image on the web instead of the httpresponsemessage, the images display just fine.

Comment: `src` of `img` element **must point to a location from where the web browser will download the image**. It is not the server that will send the image content to the `img`.

Comment: @Derija93 it returns the actual image contents... I can't access the images directly through a URI- or rather I can, but I need to resize them and can do that in C# easily here.... so this is kind of step one :)

Comment: @Nicros if the api returns the actual image, then why the ajax call in the first place?

Comment: Oh, I see. This is your approach to your previous question. :)

Comment: @zeroflagL I think the answer lies in the POST variables that are sent with the request. The images are unavailable for HTTP requests. Now if he was using a GET request though, it would be much easier...

Comment: @Derija93 Sure, but it's his own API ;)

Comment: @zeroflagL Good point. Lemme just expand my answer... I wish it was possible to properly accredit someone as contributor to an answer should it be accepted. Matter of fact, it's your idea, so why not make an answer yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest an alternative solution. If you would / could make your API accept GET calls then things would be much easier:

```
var $img = $('<img/>', {
             src: "/reporter/api/image/getimage/?path=" + httpNonAccessibleFilePath
           });   
$( "#imagecontent" ).append( $img);
```

No AJAX call needed.

Comment: I like this approach as well- I thought of it, but my path parameter is crazy `\\localfile\long\path\to\image.jpg`.  I tried encodeURI on that path but I get an HttpReponseException on my REST side that I haven't figured out yet.  Will keep trying.

Comment: Works!  On the jQuery side, the encodeURI plus a correct signature on the GET method in the api and this was perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return an URL pointing to image location, which can be your server method producing images.

Basically, you reverted the logics of how `img` tag works: `src` of `img` element **must point to a location from where the web browser will download the image**. It is not the server that will send the image content to the `img`.

What needs to be done, thus, is to return URL like `/dynamic-images/image-1.jpg` and intercept requests on that path so that they'd return *actual* content.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I see, you are sending the file contents in response to the AJAX request. As @skuntsel pointed out in his comment, the `src` attribute must point to a URI. However, there is a solution to this. Have a look at the [data:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) URI scheme. It does exactly what you are looking for, just needs a little more information.

It would look like this, since you're using PNG:

```
$('#imagecontent').append('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + imageData + '" />');
```

See [Data: Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Format) on the same Wikipedia article. Obviously this will work only for browsers that support it... it's quite a young technique.

Comment: I did give this a go, but I was unable to get this to work... but zeroflagL's solution using GET worked great

Comment: @Nicros I guess the problem here was that the data: URI scheme currently only takes base64 encoded data. Probably your data sent was all in bytes. You would have needed some sort of conversion... considering that, zeroflagL's solution is the simplest and most supported. ;)